# Perl regex efficient way to keep matching sub-string?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to clean up some sloppy address fields in a csv.

```
start_of_lineA,="123456789",end_of_lineA
start_of_lineB,="234560000",end_of_lineB
start_of_lineC,34567,end_of_lineC
```

that I'm cleaning up to:

```
start_of_lineA,12345,end_of_lineA
start_of_lineB,23456,end_of_lineB
start_of_lineC,34567,end_of_lineC
```

And some street address entries that contain commas which I can just drop:

```
start_of_lineD,"123 Foo St, #1",End_of_lineD
start_of_lineE,"456 Bar Lane, suite A, B",End_of_lineE
```

to:

```
start_of_lineD,"123 Foo St",End_of_lineD
start_of_lineE,"456 Bar Lane",End_of_lineE
```

So far what I've come up with is:

```
  chomp;
  if($_ =~ m/="/)
  {
    $_ =~ s/="\d{5}\K\d*"//g;
    $_ =~ s/="//g;
  }
  if($_ =~ m/"[^"|^,]+,[^"]*"/)
  {
    $_ =~ s/"[^"|^,]+\K,[^"]*"//g;
    $_=~ s/"//g;
  }
  @line = split(/,/,$_);
  etc.
```

While it works, it seems inelegant. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters:

```
$_ =~
```

Is usually redundant.

Otherwise - use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) and parse it:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV -> new (); 
while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( $filehandle ) ) { 
    $row -> [1] =~ s/=\"(\d+)\"/$1/;
    $row -> [1] =~ s/,//g; 
    $csv -> print ( \*STDOUT, $row ); 
}
```